# D-Link DES-1210/28P VLAN Configuration

Tags: vlan, trunk

Hi i have the below requirement to be configured on DES-1210-28P

Create  4 VLANS

VLAN 296
VLAN 2910
VLAN 101
VLAN 102

Configure VLANS

1. Port 24 Trunk-Port to allow VLAN 296 & 2910
2. Port 23 Trunk-Port to allow VLAN 101 & 102
3. Port 22 Access-Port to allow VLAN 296
4. Port 21 Access-Port to allow VLAN 101
5. Port 20 Access-Port to allow VLAN 2910
6. Port 19 Access-Port to allow VLAN 102

Is it possible to do the above configuration in this model?

Comment: Apparently, that switch model has extensive layer-2 features, including VLANs.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer is "yes," but I suspect that doesn't fully meet your needs.

I found a manual here [ https://eu.dlink.com/uk/en/-/media/business_products/des/des-1210-series/manual/des_1210_series_c1_manual_v4_00.pdf ] that has relevant information.

The configuration you are looking for isn't covered in detail in that document, but page 38 describes a more complex configuration that covers details you will need to implement your approach, including showing a screenshot of the web UI for adding and configuring VLANs on page 39, and for setting the PVID, also on page 39.